# How to perform an update using ObjectContext

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I am using EF4 in my ASP.NET MVC 2 web application. I am attempting to save data to a database. It is fairly straightforward to *add* new data to a database. I'm doing it something like this:

```
PeopleEntities entities = ObjectContextFactory.GetPeopleEntities();
entities.People.AddObject(person); // The Person object created from user input.
entities.SaveChanges();
```

However, this has the unfortunate side-effect of always saving a new object to my database. I do need this functionality (of course), but I also want the option to update an existing item in the database (or, save as new if the item does not yet exist in the database).

I tried replacing the second line above with something like this:

```
entities.People.ApplyCurrentValues(person);
```

but I am receiving this InvalidOperationException:

> An object with a key that matches the
>   key of the supplied object could not
>   be found in the ObjectStateManager.
>   Verify that the key values of the
>   supplied object match the key values
>   of the object to which changes must be
>   applied.

This case happens whether I try to add a new person, or if I am trying to edit a person. What can I do to correct this issue?

**Update to Question:**

I tried the answers provided below, but when I went to debug the `Single` statement, I found that the ID of the Person I was saving was always 0 - even if I had retrieved it from the database. So, I wanted to post what I am doing to retrieve the web application in the first place. Maybe this will help a bit.

When I navigate to a page displaying a Person's information, the address is:

http://localhost/Person/Index/1

where 1 is the ID of the Person in the database. I retrieve the Person through a repository method that contains the following line (entities is a member variable of the repository class):

```
public Person GetPerson(int id)
{
    return entities.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PersonID == id);
}
```

This method is called from my project's controller. That looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var entities = ObjectContextFactory.GetScenarioDBEntities();
    Person person = new PersonRepository(entities).GetPerson(id);
    return View("Index", person);
}
```

Now that I am looking at that, I wonder if it's wrong to instantiate a local entities object every time I want to retrieve a new Person. (Going to research that now.) In any case, when I do, ultimately go to save over the previous Person, I find that the PersonID value is always == 0.

Comment: that's bizarre - so are you saying if you have a Person in the DB with ID = 10, then you try and retrieve that person, the ID is 0? That doesn't make any sense. Think you need to rework your entity/context design. You shouldn't be newing up a new context each action method. You should instantiate one per HTTP request, and pass it through the ctor of the controller (preferably with a DI container)

Comment: @RPM1984 - That's why I'm confused. That's what I thought I was doing. If you read @Neil Fenwick's suggestion below (the link the he sent), I'm doing exactly that. (Kind of proud of myself that I figured that out on my own.) I think my problem may lie with how I'm sending the information BACK upon submit. That is what I have always been a little fuzzy on. Currently I'm using MVC2 strongly-typed partial pages. It seemed like I basically just needed a Controller method to take in the data on POST and I would write it out per the method above. Seems that it wasn't that easy...

Comment: @RPM1984 - From what I can tell, the reason that the ID is always 0 is because I don't use a hidden field for the ID on my editing page. However, when I do add it to the page, my solution still doesn't work. I don't feel like I have anything wrong in how I am implementing this...but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`entities.SaveChanges();` is all you need, provided you retrieved the object from the same exact context. Otherwise, you'll need a call to `entities.Attach(person);`.

This should work:

```
PeopleEntities entities = ObjectContextFactory.GetPeopleEntities();
var person  = entities.People.Single(p => p.Id == id); // or some other way to get the person in question
// make changes to person ...
entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Something weird is happening. I went to do what you said, but I'm finding that the ID of the Person that I am saving is always 0 - even if I am retrieving a Person from the database. What would cause this to happen? (I have updated my question to show what I am doing.)

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because I know it's the right answer. I believe there is a different issue in the source. Thanks.

Comment: Try opening your edmx file as XML (by right clicking and choosing "Open with..."), and scanning the file looking for comments. Sometimes problems with your data model only show up as comments in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void UpdateEntity(Entity entity) {
   var entityKeyObj = DataContext.Entity.Where(i => i.ID == entity.ID).First();
   entity.EntityKey = entityKeyObj.EntityKey;
   DataContext.ApplyCurrentValues("Units",entity);
   SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var entity = context.Table.Single(predicate);
entity.Field = "stuff";
context.SaveChanges();
```