# How to update a record by id?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am very new To EntityFramework and having trouble to understand why first code doesn't update but second does. My aim is to update a record without querying db.

Is it too obvious?

```
using (CHATDBEntities db = new CHATDBEntities())
    {
        // update buddy
        onlines buddy = new onlines();
        buddy.id = 56;
        buddy.last_seen = DateTime.Now;
        buddy.status = (int)UserStatuses.Status.Chatting;
        buddy.connected_to_id = 34;
        buddy.room_id = 2;

        db.SaveChanges();

    }

    using (CHATDBEntities db = new CHATDBEntities())
    {
        // update buddy
        var buddy = db.onlines.First();
        buddy.last_seen = DateTime.Now;
        buddy.status = (int)UserStatuses.Status.Chatting;
        buddy.connected_to_id = 34;
        buddy.room_id = 2;

        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

it looks like it is related to "id" which is primary identity key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retrieve an entity in order to update it, you can't just create a new one with the same id as a record from the database and expect EF to magically know that it needs to update the database.  You could try attaching it to the ObjectContext but that is not how you are supposed to do updates.

Comment: Hmm, do you think hand crafting an update statement would be less costly? Like Update table set a=b where id=n

Comment: Yes but why bother, what is your aversion to retrieving a record.

Comment: Just to create less overhead, i assumed updating with another query would be costlier than doing it without one

Comment: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" write software that works, then optimise if you find performance bottle necks. Retrieving the record first is unlikely to make much difference in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to add your new buddy to `onlines` collection?

```
db.onlines.Add(buddy); // << this
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: he's able to add the entity he looking for a way to update without having to hit the database, which isn't possible with EF.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you need to select the object into the ObjectContect before you can update it. It looks like the only way to update the entity is to first read it.

Please see this other [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630035/how-to-perform-an-update-using-objectcontext) link which answers this.

Comment: As I stated, I already know the buddy id and don't want to re-query database.

Comment: Sorry about that, got trigger happy. :)